# How to prevent Add/Remove Programs entry after WiX MBA installer bundle installs .NET Framework prerequisite

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, wix3, wix3.11

I have a WiX bundle installer with a custom managed bootstrapper application. The bundle installs .NET 4.8 as a prerequisite, using `WixMbaPrereqPackageId`. I found that if the installer installs .NET, but then the user cancels out of the actual installer before running it, my application will appear in the "Add or remove programs" list in Windows.

According to [this WiX GitHub issue](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4014), it seems like this is designed behavior. I would prefer if the entry wasn't added though, since no components of my application were actually installed. Is there a good way to prevent this entry from being added, or to remove it appropriately (without registry editing)?

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved in WiX v4. For information about the multiple issues involved, see https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4822#issuecomment-743487162.